# Is it possible to bind a property to value of a setter?

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to bind a property to value of a setter like this

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding updateToolTip}"/>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Setters don't have values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can bind provided that `updateToolTip` is publically \ internally found in the data context of the UI control for which the tooltip setter is targetted.

Answer (score 0):

When you say its not working, do you mean it gives you an error or wrong content? It works for me: (it is the value of the property not the setter though)

XAML

```
 <Button Click="Button_Click">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding MySelectedItem}"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfValues}"   SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Code:

```
 public string MySelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedValueString;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedValueString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't see why this is not working for you, is it possible to show more code?